# VueJs + Firestore realtime listeners and update changes

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'am working with vuejs and firestore.I'am trynig to make my data change without refreshing page. the code below add me new line when i change the value on firestore.

value before changing:

[image: value before changing]

value after changing:

[image: value after changing]

my code:

[image: my code]

```
{
<template>

  <div id="dashboard">
    <ul class="collection with-header">
      <li class="collection-header"><h4>PLC</h4></li>
      <li v-for="post in plc_value" v-bind:key="" class="collection-item">
        <div class="chip">{{post.value_g}}</div>
        <router-link class="secondary-content" v-bind:to="{ name: '', params:{} }"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import db from './firebaseInit';
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  data() {
    return {
      plc_value: [],
  //    loading: true
    };
  },
  created() {
    db
      .collection('plc_value')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            id: doc.id,
            value_g: doc.data().value_g
          };
          this.plc_value.push(data);
        });
      });
  }


};
</script>

}
```

Comment: <script>
import db from './firebaseInit';
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  data() {
    return {
      plc_value: [],
  //    loading: true
    };
  },
  created() {
    db
      .collection('plc_value')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            id: doc.id,
            value_g: doc.data().value_g
          };
          this.plc_value.push(data);
        });
      });
  }
};

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You added the same picture twice. You should also add the relevant code directly to your question, instead of as a comment. Please edit your question to clarify. It is also helpful, if your code snippet is executable and one can directly reproduce your problem.

Comment: is it clear now ?? actually, am trying to build a realtime application. my value on database(firestore) is always changing and i have to display that change on my site without need to refresh my page.

Comment: Can you add the code as text through an [edit]?

Comment: <script>
import db from './firebaseInit';
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  data() {
    return {
      plc_value: [],
  //    loading: true
    };
  },
  created() {
    db
      .collection('plc_value')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            id: doc.id,
            value_g: doc.data().value_g
          };
          this.plc_value.push(data);
        });
      });
  }


};
</script>     here's my code

Comment: I HAVE posted my code. i think i have to chage something in my <template>

Answer (score 2):

In your `created` function, do this:

```
 created() {
    db
      .collection('plc_value')
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const documents = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          const data = {
            id: doc.id,
            value_g: doc.data()
          }
            return data
        });
          this.plc_value.push(documents);
        });
      });
  }
```